# Trouble understanding the source code of different instances of `MonadPlus` typeclass

Tags: haskell, monads, alternative-functor

I'm going through the source code of the `MonadPlus` typeclass and its instances like `Maybe`, `[]` etc. I don't find the methods of these instances - `mzero` or `mplus` defined. Here's the [source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#MonadPlus) of `Maybe` instance of `MonadPlus`:

```
class (Alternative m, Monad m) => MonadPlus m where
   mzero :: m a
   mzero = empty

   mplus :: m a -> m a -> m a
   mplus = (<|>)

instance MonadPlus Maybe
```

While in [Chapter 15](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/programming-with-monads.html#monadcase.monadplus) of Real World Haskell it says that the following are the standard definitions of `mzero` and `mplus` for `Maybe` and `[]`.

```
class Monad m => MonadPlus m where
   mzero :: m a 
   mplus :: m a -> m a -> m a

instance MonadPlus [] where
   mzero = []
   mplus = (++)

instance MonadPlus Maybe where
   mzero = Nothing

   Nothing `mplus` ys  = ys
   xs      `mplus` _ = xs
```

So essentially my question is why there's the difference?

Comment: `empty` and `(<|>)` are the **default** definitions for `MonadPlus`. That doesn't mean that lists and Maybe can't overwrite those definitions. Although, `empty` for Maybes is `Nothing`, and `(<|>)` for Maybes is your "standard definition" of `mplus`, so they don't need to overwrite anything.

Comment: @Aplet123 I understand it now. I've never seen an instance with no methods before so I was a bit confused. Thank you!

Comment: @Aplet123 Can you convert your comment into an answer please? Its best to avoid answering questions in comments.

Comment: Look at the `MINIMAL` pragma, for example a simple type class `Eq` has default methods (but you cannot give an empty instance) and the following pragma: `{-# MINIMAL (==) | (/=) #-}` you only need to define `a == b` (in which case `a /= b` = `not (a == b)`) or `a /= b` (and `a == b` is then `not (a == b)`). But you only need to define one. Good luck on your Haskelling

Comment: @Iceland_jack So, basically `MINIMAL` pragma, tells us what method must be implemented by all instances. If there is no `MINIMAL` pragma like in the case of `MonadPlus` then we don't need its instances to implement any of the methods(`mzero` and `mplus`). Am I right? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mzero = empty` and `mplus = (<|>)` lines specify default implementations, which any implementor can override. `empty` and `(<|>)` come from the [`Alternative` typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#g:2), which is defined for Maybes and lists as such:

```hs
instance Alternative Maybe where
    empty = Nothing
    Nothing <|> r = r
    l       <|> _ = l

instance Alternative [] where
    empty = []
    (<|>) = (++)
```

So, the `Alternative` definitions already match the default `MonadPlus` definitions, so they can simply write `instance MonadPlus Maybe` and use the defaults.

Essentially, the standard definition is still correct, it just expands out the defaults and takes `Alternative` out of the picture.